# T-sql to find backup folder for specific maintenance plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, backup, maintenance-plan

I have to check multiple servers daily to find their backup folders (and maybe other data, like backup time, databases and backuptype).

Is there anyway to write a script to list the backup folder if I know the name of the Maintenance Plan?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292134/sql-server-2008-maintenance-plan-backup-list) helpful, but it requires the backup to have been run at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Configure/Enable [database mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245116.aspx).

Then just create an operator for each job, everytime the job fail, the operator will send out an email.

[This link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1523/how-to-setup-sql-server-alerts-and-email-operator-notifications/) has a detailed approach, on how to configure your alerts.

Comment: Thank you. :)

I wish to automate the procedure and I'm looking into SSIS and powershell options, alas, currently without any luck.